# max_input_vars: how many am I using?

Tags: php, theme-development, theme-options

I'm processing a large amount of Options in a Wordpress theme.

I want to ensure I keep below the default 1000 before hitting a `max_input_vars` error.

Is there a way to test how many 'input_vars' I'm generating?

(sorry, doubting I'm using the correct terminology here - hoping I make sense)

Comment: Use `phpinfo()` function to check the current `max_input_vars` parameter value

Comment: Thank you but this doesn't really help me. I know how to see/increase this setting on my server. I want to know how many I'm using since I want to keep it under 1000 (I don't want any of my users having to start to edit things like their php.ini file, etc)

Answer (score 3):

`max_input_vars` is the limit on the total number of GET, POST, and COOKIE vars. To determine how many there are you can just `count` them.

Here's a quick example in a WordPress context:

```
function wpd_admin_error_notice() {
    echo 'This request contained ' . count( $_POST ) . ' POST vars, ' . count( $_GET ) . ' GET vars, and ' . count( $_COOKIE ) . ' Cookies.'; 
}
add_action( 'admin_notices', 'wpd_admin_error_notice' );
```

Of course, the above will not be entirely helpful for your purposes, because WordPress uses the standard [post / redirect / get](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern for admin form submissions. You'll have to hook the above code to an action that runs when your options are saved, and log them to a file or the db.